# Invalid argument when calling linux splice()

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, splice

I wanted to try out the splice syscall. I have this function - it should copy content of one file to another:

```
static void test_splice( int in, int out ) {

        int i = 0, rcvd = 0;
        int filedes[2];
        off_t off = 0;

        if ( pipe( filedes ) < 0 ) {
                perror( "Kicha pipe" );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        for ( i = 0; i < NUMLOOPS; ++i ) {

                if ( ( rcvd = splice( in, NULL, filedes[1], NULL, BUFSIZE, SPLICE_F_MORE | SPLICE_F_MOVE ) ) < 0 ) {
                        perror( "splice" );
                        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                }

                if ( splice( filedes[0], NULL, out, NULL, rcvd, SPLICE_F_MORE | SPLICE_F_MOVE ) < 0 ) {
                        perror( "splice" );
                        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                }
        }
}
```

The second call to splice in first iteration returns EINVAL ( invalid argument from perror ) everytime - what could be the reason?

Comment: What kind of file system(s) are your files on?

Comment: Both ext3, but I also tried reading from /dev/zero and writing to /dev/null with the same error.

Comment: I just solved it - I opened the file using fopen with mode "a+" - when changed to "w" - it worked.

Answer (score 1):

From [`splice(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/splice):

```
ERRORS
       ...    
       EINVAL Target  filesystem  doesn't  support  splicing;  target  file is
              opened in append mode; neither of the file descriptors refers to
              a pipe; or offset given for nonseekable device.
       ...
```

OP's comment indicated that he opened the file in append mode.

Answer (score -1):

I have no idea whether this is the best way of doing this, but this works for me:

http://vectrex.org.uk/mark/splicecopy.cpp

It creates one thread to read and another for writing. This may be unnecessary. The writing thread only appears to require one splice() call, but the reader does approximately every 64k on my system.

The above was tested on Fedora 13 x86_64 and appears to be able to copy larg(ish) files.